# Out of range error in firebug console

Tags: javascript, firefox, extjs, firebug, javascript-debugger

I am trying to debug ext-all-debug-w-comments.js file. The file is pretty big and when the error occurs, it says "`TypeError: all.item(...) is null (151559 out of range 149122)`"

Basically the error occurs at line number 151559 but only 149122 files are shown in firebug. Since all the lines are not loaded I cannot debug in firebug.

Please see below image for more information
[image]

What should option I have here?

Thank you

Comment: Does it help if you increase extensions.firebug.cache.responseLimit to a higher value in about:config? (We're currently adding an automatic notification about that. It's kindof problematic, because the only way we have of getting script sources is caching every request, and doing that without a memory limit increases memory usage a lot.)

Comment: @SimonLindholm : Thank you for the reply. Can you please tell me how can I update xtensions.firebug.cache.responseLimit to a higher value in about:config. I am not sure where will I find this setting.

Comment: Maybe you should try the version without comments?

Comment: Visit about:config, search for extensions.firebug.cache.responseLimit through the input field, and double-click the preference to set a new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a browser specific issue involved?

If not, you could use Chrome, it can handle bigger scripts compared to Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Use ext-dev.js instead. The ext-all- files are compiled versions with all classes available in Ext JS; ext-dev.js will load every class you use in a separate file. Slows down the app loading considerably so it's only suitable for debugging, but it also makes Ext JS a lot easier to debug.

In order to use ext-dev.js you'll need to set the paths to Ext JS and your custom classes using [Ext.Loader.setPath](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Loader-method-setPath), before the first classes are required -- at the top of your app.js would probably be the best place.

Another (better) way to manage dependencies is to use [Sencha Cmd](http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/3.1.2/#!/guide/command).